# Hard join. Is it possible?

Tags: sql

I need to get the forum name, thread name and post message with the post id 32.

Would this be possible to do with 1 query?

forums

- id
- name

threads

- id
- forumid
- subject

posts

- id
- threadid
- message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT f.name, t.subject, p.message
FROM posts AS p
INNER JOIN threads AS t
  ON p.threadid = t.id
INNER JOIN forums AS f
  ON t.forumid = f.id
WHERE p.id = 32
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from forums f 
     join threads t on f.id = t.forumid 
     join posts p on p.threadid = threads.id 
where p.id = 32
```

Comment: Of course, it's generally a bad idea to return all columns indiscriminately, and it would be better to specify the columns required (f.name, t.subject, p.message in this instance)

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem?

```
select name, subject, message from posts join threads on (threadid=posts.id) join forums on (forumid=forums.id) where posts.id=32
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the id of the post to see well the row

```
SELECT p.id ,p.message,t.subject, f.name
FROM forums AS f
RIGHT OUTER JOIN threads AS t
ON f.id = t.forumid
RIGHT OUTER JOIN posts AS p
ON t.id = p.threadid
WHERE p.id = 32
```

Tested on MySql